# Writing a function to get days in a range grouped by month and perform some simple calculations on them

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a function in mySQL that takes two dates(startDate and endDate) as parameters. It then calculates the days in each month.

The database contains a targetRevenue table that has got the target revenue values for each month and year.

```
id  month   year  targetRev
25    1       2012    1000.00
26    2       2012    5000.00
27    3       2012    8000.00
```

The function finds the revenue for a month based on the number of days in it and then returns the total.

Example :  startDate : 2012-01-19 endDate : 2012-03-24
Function returns  [ targetRev(19 days in Jan) + targetRev(29 days Feb) + targetRev(24days in March)]

I am new to writing functions in mysql , so a little bit of help to get me started would be very useful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If instead of your `month` and `year` columns, you represented the month of each record in your `targetRevenue` table by a `DATE` column containing the first day of each month:

```
ALTER TABLE targetRevenue
  ADD COLUMN first DATE;

UPDATE targetRevenue
  SET first = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', year, month, 1), '%Y-%c-%e');

ALTER TABLE targetRevenue
  DROP COLUMN year,
  DROP COLUMN month;
```

You could then obtain the total target revenue for your project (assuming it is inclusive of both start and end date) with:

```
-- calculate the summation of
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(

         -- number of project days in month...
         GREATEST(0,
           -- ...is calculated as the difference between...
           DATEDIFF(
             -- ...the last day of the project in this month...
                LEAST('2012-03-24', LAST_DAY(first)),
             -- ...and the first day of the project in this month...
             GREATEST('2012-01-19', first)
           )
           -- ...plus one because first and last project days were inclusive
           + 1
         )

         -- multiply by the target revenue for this month
         * targetRev

         -- divide by the number of days in the month
         / DAY(LAST_DAY(first)),

         -- convert result to fixed-point format, to two d.p.
         DECIMAL(11,2)

       )) AS total

FROM   targetRevenue

-- only perform for months in which the project was active
WHERE  '2012-01-19' <= LAST_DAY(first) AND first <= '2012-03-24'
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3515/1/0).

If you can't change the schema, you could replace references to `first` with the value to which that column was updated above.

Comment: Thanks so much!! This is indeed a very useful solution and it works exactly the way I wanted it to:) If I were to use a function for doing this, that accepts two dates as parameters and returns the revenue total, could I update the value of first in the function and not make any changes to the schema?

Comment: @user1611418: You wouldn't need to perform any update, but rather calculate the value of `first` in the query.  It'll just perform slower than the above, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use `SUM()` function like:

```
SELECT SUM(targetRev) from your_table
WHERE  date_column BETWEEN your_startDate_column AND your_endDate_column;
```

you need not to calculate days of each month..

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But the reason I would need to calculate days in each month is because, the target_Revenue values in the table are for the entire month , so if a date is something like 24-03-2012, first I would need to calculate the mar revenue as (24* target_revenue)/31

Answer (score 0):

Use this query like this

```
SELECT   SUM(targetRev), MONTH(date_column) as mo
from     your_table
WHERE    date_column BETWEEN your_startDate AND your_endDate
GROUP BY mo;
```

This will give the result for each month total revenue (use like this logic)

If it is two different years you can use like

```
concat(year(date_column),month(date_column)) as mo
```